# Setting image for tabbarcontroller?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is any way to set image for tabbarcontroller ? Means a common background image for all the tab ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TabBar Controller is not visible to the user. What the user can see is the TabBar itself. That's just to avoid misunderstandings. For your question: There is no officialy supported way, sorry.